# Interchange Integration and Minimization

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, calculus-of-variations, integral-operators

I am new to calculus of variations and I have a problem of the type
\begin{equation*}
\text{min}_{g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,g(x))\, \mathrm dx,
\end{equation*}
where $f$ is absolutely integrable and $f\geq 0$. I am able to solve this problem using a classical variational approach. However, as $f\geq 0$ I am wondering whether it is posible to interchange the minimum and the integral and solve
\begin{equation*}
\text{min}_{g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})}\,\, f(x,g(x)) \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
instead. I would be very happy if someone has any ideas on how to prove/falsify this!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that
$$
\min_{g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})}f(x,g(x))
$$
is rather "ill-defined". It can only be taken in the point-wise sense, which is to say that there exists a $\bar{g} \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. for all $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$
f(g(x),x) \geq f(\bar{g}(x),x) \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
This pointwise condition is way too strong and is indeed fully sufficient:
We could just use monoticity of the integral w.r.t. its integrand and see that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(g(x),x)dx \geq \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\bar{g}(x),x)dx
$$
And by definition, it would be the minimum. While this could be useful in certain situations for specific choices of $f(p,x)$, it is not useful in general as the point-wise minimization problem is much harder to solve than the one involving the integral.
As you already mentioned, Hilbert space/functional analysis methods (or the direct method, as it is often called) will provide you with an existence results way faster.

Comment: Thank you very much! You answer was very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome :-)